# Changing default line height in avalon edit

Tags: c#, avalonedit

I am writing a custom software using avalon edit and I am looking for a way to make the space (height) between lines bigger. At the moment I am forced to add an empty line every time the user has ended writing a line and wants to write another.

I have started looking into the `TextView` Class where defaultLineHeight seems to be calculated but the only thing I was able to affect is the height of the visual caret but not the content itself.

At the moment I am looking at making every pair line invisible but I am hoping there is an easier way to achieve the simple operation of adding more space between lines.

Here is the method from class `TextView` I am inspecting at the moment. Any tips or hints would be welcome.

```
void CalculateDefaultTextMetrics()
{
    if (defaultTextMetricsValid)
    {
        return;
    }

    defaultTextMetricsValid = true;
    if (formatter != null)
    {
        var textRunProperties = CreateGlobalTextRunProperties();
        using (
            var line = formatter.FormatLine(
                new SimpleTextSource("x", textRunProperties),
                0,
                32000,
                new VisualLineTextParagraphProperties { defaultTextRunProperties = textRunProperties },
                null))
        {
            wideSpaceWidth = Math.Max(1, line.WidthIncludingTrailingWhitespace);
            defaultBaseline = Math.Max(1, line.Baseline);
            defaultLineHeight = Math.Max(1, line.Height);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wideSpaceWidth = FontSize / 2;
        defaultBaseline = FontSize;
        **defaultLineHeight = FontSize + 3; // bigger value only affects caret height :(**
    }

    // Update heightTree.DefaultLineHeight, if a document is loaded.
    if (heightTree != null)
    {
        heightTree.DefaultLineHeight = defaultLineHeight;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DefaultLineHeight` is the height of a line in the default font, which is used as an initial assumption for the each line's height. (e.g. for calculating the scroll bar position)

Whenever a line gets actually measured (`TextView.BuildVisualLine`), the measured height gets stored in the height tree, overwriting the default height. This is because word wrapping (or a line transformer changing the font size) can cause each line to have a different height.

Inter-line spacing isn't really supported at the moment. If you want to add that, you can try changing the height calculation of the `VisualLine`, e.g. by changing `VisualLine.SetTextLines()`.

Answer (score 3):

Including what @Peter Moore said. There's one more step required in order to force the text to render correctly.

At the bottom of `VisualLine.cs` lies the class `VisualLineDrawingVisual` which is responsible for drawing the actual text but doesn't have access to the `TextView` class.

Modify the constructor to include `double lineSpacing` as a paremeter and multiply all instances of `textLine.Height` by `lineSpacing`.

In `VisualLine.Render()`, pass `textView.LineSpacing` as the secondary parameter for the now-modified constructor for `VisualLineDrawingVisual`. After this everything should draw correctly.

**Here's a full view of the modified code:**

TextView.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LineSpacingProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LineSpacing", typeof(double), typeof(TextView),
                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0));

public double LineSpacing {
    get { return (double) GetValue(LineSpacingProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LineSpacingProperty, value); }
}
```

VisualLine.cs

*Line 269*

```
internal void SetTextLines(List<TextLine> textLines) {
    this.textLines = textLines.AsReadOnly();
    Height = 0;
    foreach (TextLine line in textLines)
        Height += line.Height * textView.LineSpacing;
}
```

*Line 335*

```
public double GetTextLineVisualYPosition(TextLine textLine, VisualYPosition yPositionMode) {
    if (textLine == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("textLine");
    double pos = VisualTop;
    foreach (TextLine tl in TextLines) {
        if (tl == textLine) {
            switch (yPositionMode) {
            case VisualYPosition.LineTop:
                return pos;
            case VisualYPosition.LineMiddle:
                return pos + tl.Height / 2 * textView.LineSpacing;
            case VisualYPosition.LineBottom:
                return pos + tl.Height * textView.LineSpacing;
            case VisualYPosition.TextTop:
                return pos + tl.Baseline - textView.DefaultBaseline;
            case VisualYPosition.TextBottom:
                return pos + tl.Baseline - textView.DefaultBaseline + textView.DefaultLineHeight;
            case VisualYPosition.TextMiddle:
                return pos + tl.Baseline - textView.DefaultBaseline + textView.DefaultLineHeight / 2;
            case VisualYPosition.Baseline:
                return pos + tl.Baseline;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid yPositionMode:" + yPositionMode);
            }
        }
        else {
            pos += tl.Height * textView.LineSpacing;
        }
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("textLine is not a line in this VisualLine");
}
```

*Line 386*

```
public TextLine GetTextLineByVisualYPosition(double visualTop) {
    const double epsilon = 0.0001;
    double pos = this.VisualTop;
    foreach (TextLine tl in TextLines) {
        pos += tl.Height * textView.LineSpacing;
        if (visualTop + epsilon < pos)
            return tl;
    }
    return TextLines[TextLines.Count - 1];
}
```

*Line 701*

```
internal VisualLineDrawingVisual Render() {
    Debug.Assert(phase == LifetimePhase.Live);
    if (visual == null)
        visual = new VisualLineDrawingVisual(this, textView.LineSpacing);
    return visual;
}
```

*Line 714*

```
public VisualLineDrawingVisual(VisualLine visualLine, double lineSpacing) {
    this.VisualLine = visualLine;
    var drawingContext = RenderOpen();
    double pos = 0;
    foreach (TextLine textLine in visualLine.TextLines) {
        textLine.Draw(drawingContext, new Point(0, pos), InvertAxes.None);
        pos += textLine.Height * lineSpacing;
    }
    this.Height = pos;
    drawingContext.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I just came across this with the same question. I managed to add line spacing very easily with the following modifications:

1. Add a new `double` dependency property to `TextView` called `LineSpacing` with a default value of `1.0`
2. In `VisualLine.SetTextLines`, multiply `line.Height` by `textView.LineSpacing`
3. In `VisualLine.GetTextLineVisualYPosition` and `VisualLine.GetTextLineByVisualYPosition`, multiply each occurrence of `tl.Height` by `textView.LineSpacing`

Then you can set `TextView.LineSpacing` directly in code or through a custom XAML style, etc.

That seemed to be all that was necessary.

PS - AvalonEdit is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Robert Jordan said, there is a couple more changes i had to make to get a satisfactory result.

First off, to make the text marking overlay to cover the entire height of the line, change the following lines in BackgroundGeometryBuilder.cs

ProcessTextLines method, line 196:

*Line 215:*

```
yield return new Rect(pos, y, 1, line.Height * textView.LineSpacing);
```

*Line 259:*

```
lastRect = new Rect(Math.Min(left, right), y, Math.Abs(right - left), line.Height * textView.LineSpacing);
```

*Line 259:*

```
Rect extendSelection = new Rect(Math.Min(left, right), y, Math.Abs(right - left), line.Height * textView.LineSpacing);
```

The second issue i had was that the text was rendered at the top of the now extended line height, not the bottom. To fix that, the extra space needs to be added before the line is rendered, not after. So make the following changes:

VisualLine.cs, Line 714

```
public VisualLineDrawingVisual(VisualLine visualLine, double lineSpacing) {
    this.VisualLine = visualLine;
    var drawingContext = RenderOpen();
    double pos = 0;
    foreach (TextLine textLine in visualLine.TextLines) {
        pos +=(textLine.Height * lineSpacing)-textLine.Height
        textLine.Draw(drawingContext, new Point(0, pos), InvertAxes.None);
        pos += textLine.Height;
    }
    this.Height = pos;
    drawingContext.Close();
}
```

In addition, i found it trivial to convert this to support dynamic line-by-line line spacings. Just move the LineSpacing property to VisualLine, then add a VisualLineTransformer like this:

```
class LinePaddingTransformer : IVisualLineTransformer
{
    public LinePaddingTransformer()
    {

    }
    public void Transform(ITextRunConstructionContext context, IList<VisualLineElement> elements)
    {
        int index = context.VisualLine.FirstDocumentLine.LineNumber - 1;
       //You need to calculate your padding from the line index somehow.
       //for example create a list of objects with the spacing in them and pass to this transformer.
        double spacing= MyCalculateLinePaddingMethod(index);  
        context.VisualLine.LineSpacing= spacing;
    }
}
```

If you require the spacing to only be added to the first line in case of text wrapping, you need to go over every single place you previously multiplied with the LineSpacing property and put a check if the TextLine is the first line in the collection.

Comment: This is great! I was trying to tackle some of these issues on my own as well but wasn't really sure what I was doing and ended up with very broken results. This'll be really helpful!