# Change line height in AvalonEdit 5.x

Tags: c#, avalonedit

This is a follow up of this post [Changing default line height in avalon edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205676/changing-default-line-height-in-avalon-edit).  Since you can't ask a question in that post, I have to ask the same question on a new post apparently. This follows Peter Moore's post where he explains how to increase the line height.

I think I have implemented it as he states but it doesn't seem to increase the height/placement of the actual editor text but does increase the height of where the text should be and the line numbers.  Please see image below.

Any ideas on how I can fix the height of the editor text as well?

In TextView.cs:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LineSpacingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LineSpacing", typeof(double), typeof(TextView),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1.0));

    public double LineSpacing
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LineSpacingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LineSpacingProperty, value); }
    }
```

In VisualLine.cs (VisualLine.SetTextLines):

```
    internal void SetTextLines(List<TextLine> textLines)
    {
        this.textLines = textLines.AsReadOnly();
        Height = 0;
        TextView textView = new TextView();

        foreach (TextLine line in textLines)
            Height += (line.Height * textView.LineSpacing);
    }
```

(VisualLine.GetTextLineVisualYPosition):

```
    public double GetTextLineVisualYPosition(TextLine textLine, VisualYPosition yPositionMode)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView();

        if (textLine == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textLine");
        double pos = VisualTop;
        foreach (TextLine tl in TextLines)
        {
            if (tl == textLine)
            {
                switch (yPositionMode)
                {
                    case VisualYPosition.LineTop:
                        return pos;
                    case VisualYPosition.LineMiddle:
                        return pos + (tl.Height * textView.LineSpacing) / 2;
                    case VisualYPosition.LineBottom:
                        return pos + (tl.Height * textView.LineSpacing);
                    case VisualYPosition.TextTop:
                        return pos + tl.Baseline - textView.DefaultBaseline;
                    case VisualYPosition.TextBottom:
                        return pos + tl.Baseline - textView.DefaultBaseline + textView.DefaultLineHeight;
                    case VisualYPosition.TextMiddle:
                        return pos + tl.Baseline - textView.DefaultBaseline + textView.DefaultLineHeight / 2;
                    case VisualYPosition.Baseline:
                        return pos + tl.Baseline;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid yPositionMode:" + yPositionMode);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                pos += (tl.Height * textView.LineSpacing);
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("textLine is not a line in this VisualLine");
    }
```

Then in (VisualLine.GetTextLineByVisualYPosition):

```
    public TextLine GetTextLineByVisualYPosition(double visualTop)
    {
        TextView textView = new TextView();

        const double epsilon = 0.0001;
        double pos = this.VisualTop;
        foreach (TextLine tl in TextLines)
        {
            pos += (tl.Height * textView.LineSpacing);
            if (visualTop + epsilon < pos)
                return tl;
        }
        return TextLines[TextLines.Count - 1];
    }
```

Finally in my window class:

```
        textEditor.TextArea.TextView.LineSpacing = 3.5f;
```

The spacing doesn't work when changed here, but it does if I change it directly in the dependency property.  Also, this only changes the line spacing of the line numbers and the editor but, the editor "text" position is unchanged.  Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: I managed to create a solution and answered the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205676/changing-default-line-height-in-avalon-edit/47897736#47897736